# Time complexity of checking whether a set is contained in another set

Tags: python-3.x, set, sliding-window

I am trying to implement the example of finding the shortest substring of a given string `s` containing the pattern `char`. My code is working fine, but my goal is to attain the time complexity of `O(N)` where N is length of `s`.
Here is my code;

```
def shortest_subtstring(s,char):
#smallest substring containing char.use sliding window
start=0
d=defaultdict(int)
minimum=9999
for i in range(len(s)):
    d[s[i]]+=1
    #check whether all the characters from char has been visited.
    while set(char).issubset(set([j for j in d if d[j]>0])):
        #if yes, can we make it shorter

        length=i-start+1
        minimum=min(length,minimum)
        if length==minimum:
            s1=s[start:i+1]
        d[s[start]]-=1
        start+=1
return (minimum,s1)
```

My question is at the line;

```
 while set(char).issubset(set([j for j in d if d[j]>0]))
```

Each time I am checking whether all strings of `char` are saved in my dictionary or not, using the idea of `is.subset`. May I know how can I find the time complexity of this step in my code? Is it `O(1)` , which is true for checking wether an element exists in a set or not. Otherwise, the time complexity will be much greater than `O(N)`. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Per docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects) `s.issubset(t)` is the equivalent of `s <= t` meaning that during the operation it will test if every element in s is in t.

Best scenario:
if s is the first element of t -> O(1)

Worst case scenario:
if s in the last element of t -> O(len(t))

That is for isubset. For the list comprehension :

`j for j in d` is O(n) for getting each key

`if d[j]>0` is O(n) for comparing each value of dictionary `d`

[Here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) you can find more info.

Comment: Appreciate your reply. it seems in my case it is `O(N)` then, which can result in overall time complexity to be `O(N^2)`.