# Question regarding recursive stack while deleting middle element from stack

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, stack

I have the running code to remove the middle element from stack, that's not an issue. Here is my code;

```
def insert(stack,temp,curr,n):
#print(curr,stack)
    if curr!=n//2:
       print(curr)
       stack.append(temp)
    #return
    return

def delete_middle(stack,n,curr):
    while len(stack)>0:
       temp=stack.pop()
       delete_middle(stack,n,curr+1)
       insert(stack,temp,curr,n)
    #print(stack)
       return stack

delete_middle([2,4,1,18,34],5,0)
```

My code is working fine. But I am trying to understand how does the recursive stack work. For example, we are doing recursive call to `delete_middle()` around `5` times(same as length of list, `stack`). Each time the pointer variable , `curr` is updated to point at the current element. As you can see last value of `curr` will be 5, but since the length of stack is 0, there is no more recursive call. And then the `insert()` function is called.

Interestingly if I look at the values of `curr` inside `insert()`, we obtain following output;

```
4
3
2
1
0
```

Why is that we don't see the first value of `curr` as 5 here? I will highly appreciate some feedback here.And can I get some thoughts on its time complexity? It seems to be `O(N)` where `N` is size of the stack. But I am bit rusty about it. Will appreciate some insight here. 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Edit:***

The insert funcs will be executed **only** after the recursive funcs will use the empty stack.

```
START DELETE 0 [only one while loop executed]
START DELETE 1 [only one while loop executed]
START DELETE 2 [only one while loop executed]
START DELETE 3 [only one while loop executed]
START DELETE 4 [only one while loop executed]
START DELETE 5 [NO while loop executed because list is empty]
-------------------------
START INSERT iteration 4
END INSERT iteration 4
END DELETE 4
-------------------------
START INSERT iteration 3
END INSERT iteration 3
END DELETE 3
-------------------------
START INSERT iteration 2
END INSERT iteration 2
END DELETE 2
-------------------------
START INSERT iteration 1
END INSERT iteration 1
END DELETE 1
-------------------------
START INSERT iteration 0
END INSERT iteration 0
END DELETE 0
```

So, we have insert function (4) running first because the when the last delete_middle(5) is executed the list, stack, is empty and it doesn't run the insert function as stated:

```
while len(stack)>0:
   ...........
   insert(stack,temp,curr,n)
```

*The above in `delete_middle` with `n=5` will not be executed because `len(stack)==0`.*

How does **middle** work:

```
#first executed  delete_middle([2,4,1,18,34],5,0)
def delete_middle(stack,n,curr):                            iteration 1
    while len(stack)>0:                     initial stack   [2,4,1,18,34]   
       temp=stack.pop()               stack after removal   [2,4,1,18]
       .....
       delete_middle(stack,n,curr+1) -> becomes: delete_middle([2,4,1,18],5,1) iteration 2
                                          while len(stack)>0:                     initial stack   [2,4,1,18]   
                                          temp=stack.pop()                  stack after removal   [2,4,1]
                                          .....
                                          delete_middle(stack,n,curr+1) > becomes: delete_middle([2,4,1],5,2) and so on until stack = [] (empty)
                                          .....
      (!) During these iterations insert(stack,temp,curr,n) is not executed because:
```

How does **insert** run:

```
  delete_middle([2,4,1,18,34],5,0)
    # Iteration 1
    #delete_middle(stack,     n, curr+1)
    delete_middle([2,4,1,18], 5,   1   )
    insert not executed!
      # Iteration 2
      delete_middle([2,4,1],5,2)
      insert not executed!
        # Iteration 3
        delete_middle([2,4],5,3)
        insert not executed!
          # Iteration 4
          delete_middle([2],5,4)
          insert not executed!
            # Iteration 5
            delete_middle([],5,5) # returns nothing because it does not enter the while loop
            insert not executed!
    Only from now -> each insert will be executed from inside delete_middle!
            insert 4
              insert 3
                insert 2
                  insert 1
```

About the time complexity:

```
Time complexity = time taken to build the final list;
                = (1 pop + 1 insert) * n
                = O(n)
```

In worst-worst-case perspective, you could say that the complexity is O(n) because reducing the list size by 1 element involves appending 1 element to the list, this because you have **only** one recursion per level.(while .. return indentation)

Although pop is O(1) and the list decreases each time (O(log n)), when each `middle_delete` is called your algorithm's running time increases with the size of the input data by executing (n-1) appends in total; appending *the whole remaining list.*

[Some starting point.](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Algorithmic%20Complexity/complexity.html)

---

**END edit**

Regarding your code, yes, it works, with some limitations if I may:

1. length of the target list must be odd
2. takes some extra unnecessary* criteria (`curr,n`) [unnecessary see
   last part]
3. function not "quite properly" executed

Explanations:

1. Try for yourself
2. End of answer (have patience with me :) )
3. For instance:

In your code:

```
while len(stack)>0:
   .....
   return stack
```

Basically, it seems that you return the first value of the while loop.
Example:

```
c = 0
def func(d):
  while d < 5:
    d+=1
    return d

print(func(c))
```

The recursive effect is triggered by the clever usage of the `None` resulting func(insert) inside the while loop. It's like pulling the hand-break instead of the pedal. :)

Regarding your *questions*:

As seen bellow, (the middle func is executed  + insert func) for each element.

```
delete middle iterion 0
--------------------------
temp 34 0
delete middle iterion 1
--------------------------
temp 18 1
delete middle iterion 2
--------------------------
temp 1 2
delete middle iterion 3
--------------------------
temp 4 3
delete middle iterion 4
--------------------------
temp 2 4
delete middle iterion 5
--------------------------
======================
insert iteration 4
curr:4, stack:[], temp:2,n:5
======================
insert iteration 3
curr:3, stack:[2], temp:4,n:5
======================
insert iteration 2
curr:2, stack:[2, 4], temp:1,n:5
======================
insert iteration 1
curr:1, stack:[2, 4], temp:18,n:5
======================
insert iteration 0
curr:0, stack:[2, 4, 18], temp:34,n:5
[2, 4, 18, 34]
```

*Why is that we don't see the first value of curr as 5 here?*

If you start (`curr`) from 0, you will see iterations from 4->0, while when initial curr is 1, iteration will be 5->1; thus 5 (N) delete func calls will be triggered.

3. I refactored your code a little with a simple logic:

If you have a targeted list [1,2,..,n-1,n] and if you want to remove the middle part using recursive funcs perhaps this approach might appeal to you:

Let's start with a 0 counter `count = 0`
for each element of the list the counter will be incremented by 1 `count+=1`

Now, to eliminate one element from each side (left, right) to get to the middle, we can say: if count is 0 or count is even remove the last item from the list, if not remove the first item thus the list looses one item per iteration.

```
if count == 0 and count % 2 == 0:
 target_list.pop(-1)
else:
 target_list.pop(0)
```

Then what if the list has an even number of items? Then we will include this scenario too: `if len(target) == 2`.

Also I suggest to use one little trick, the fact that default value for a function argument is only evaluated once, at the time that the function is defined.

what I mean by this? Check example for [Common Mistake #1](https://www.toptal.com/python/top-10-mistakes-that-python-programmers-make).

To include everything from above into a final func (O(N)) :

```
def eliminate_middle(target, count=0, beg_l=[],end_l=[]):
  print(count)                                    # O(N)
  if len(target) == 1:                            # if target has only one element
    return beg_l+sorted(end_l)

  else:

    if count == 0 or count % 2 == 0:

      if len(target) == 2:                        # case len(target) is Even 
        return beg_l+sorted(end_l)                #eliminates the two middle elements

      end_l.append(target.pop(-1))                #target loses last element
      return eliminate_middle(target,count+1)

    else:

      beg_l.append(target.pop(0))                 # target loses first element
      return eliminate_middle(target, count+1)

print(eliminate_middle([2,4,1,18,34]))
```

Comment: Appreciate you taking your time to explain in details. I have couple of questions, if I may; first, I agree that the way while loop is defined, it should return right after insert function is called for the first time. May I know why is insert being called 4 times here. It's a good thing that it is called 4 times, but I really want to understand why is that happening? Second, I am still not sure about the time complexity of my algorithm.Can you kindly advise?

Comment: @jayant Added new section, from Edit to End Edit. Let me know if there is something unclear.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Got it now, how `insert()` is being called.On a side note, I was looking at the code you had suggested. My concern is since, I am working on a stack, as mentioned in the question, hence only `pop()` and `append()` are allowed. Thats the reason I am using `list` data structure but with only `pop()` and `append()` operations. In that case will it be okay to use `pop(0)` as suggested in your code above. Moreover, I did try to give an input  of even length and it seems to be working fine, i.e. deleting the element when `curr` is equal to `n//2`.

Comment: You're very welcome! And glad to hear ! about the even part - are you sure ? `delete_middle([2,4,1,2,18,34],6,0)` results `2, 4, 2, 18, 34`, e.g. `delete_middle([2,4,1,2,18,34],5,0))` results `2, 4, 1, 18, 34`, that's why (in my opinion only) perhaps it would had been better to remove both `1,2`, but ultimately you are the one who decides how's best. Also would appreciate if you select the answer. Cheers!

Comment: got your point. I can see now. But as per the requirement, one element is fine. Appreciate your detailed help. I learnt  useful concept today. Is there a method to compute time complexity for checking whether a set contained in another set? I have a question here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61151175/time-complexity-of-checking-whether-a-set-is-contained-in-another-set

Comment: You're very welcome! And thank you! Answered that too. Have a look!